# SSRS - Only load data region on request?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to load a data region (matrix) only on request. I have a screen with a few fields and a 13 week revenue tablix that can take 10 or more seconds to load. I'd like the tablix data region to only load when the user needs to see that information. My understanding of how SSRS works is that this is not possible, but I'd like to confirm. Are there any workarounds?

Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the visibility of the Matrix on the value of a paramater .

For example ,you can create a new paramter ShowParamter.

Lets say your Matrix's Id is matrix1, then under visibility set the hidden  property of matrix1 as

IIF(Paramaters!ShowParamter="True", false,true)

If the value of the paramater is true then the matrix should be seen otherwise hidden.